# Determine whether the intergral converges: $\int_1^\infty\cos(x^{3/4}) \,dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I've got the next integral from a test i had.

$$\int_1^\infty\cos(x^{3/4}) \, dx$$

I had to determine whether it converges or diverges.

I've started with Taylor summations to hopefully ease it up, So:
$$\int_1^\infty\cos(x^{3/4}) \, dx=\int_1^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{3/2}}{(2n)!} \, dx$$

But know i don't know what to do.
Anyone got a tip?

Comment: I think it's not convergent because it has a period such that on each period the integral is zero.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the power-series expansion can do anything for this problem.  It might shed light on the function's behavior near $0$, but "near $0$" is exactly what this problem is _not_ about. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: See [this related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452661/generalized-fresnel-integral-int-0-infty-sin-xp-rm-dx) question

Comment: this integral does not converge