# Convergence/divergence of the improper integral $ \intop_{1}^{\infty}\sin\left(x^{p}\right)dx $

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have to determine if the improper integral $ \intop_{1}^{\infty}\sin\left(x^{p}\right)dx $

convergent/divergent for any $ 0<p \in \mathbb{R} $

Here's what Ive done :

We can substitute  $ x^{p}=y $
and then we'll get

$ \intop_{1}^{\infty}\sin\left(x^{p}\right)dx=\intop_{1}^{\infty}y^{\frac{1-p}{p}}\sin\left(y\right) $

Thus, for $ p>1 $ the integral will converge by Dirichlet's theorem.

My intuition is that for $ p<1 $ the integral diverges.

I'll write it again, let $ \frac{1-p}{p}=\alpha $

How do we prove that $ \intop_{1}^{\infty}x^{\alpha}\sin\left(x\right)dx $ diverge for $ \alpha > 0 $ ?

I tried to show that $ x^{\alpha}\sin\left(x\right) $ will not follow Cauchy's condition but it got complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some related content [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452661/generalized-fresnel-integral-int-0-infty-sin-xp-rm-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \int_{\pi}^{n\pi} x^{\alpha}\sin(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}x^{\alpha}\sin(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k\int_{0}^{\pi}(u+k\pi)^{\alpha}\sin(u)du $$
The integral $\int_{0}^{\pi}(u+k\pi)^{\alpha}\sin(u)du$ does not converge to $0$ as $k\rightarrow +\infty$ because, using $\sin(x)\geqslant\frac{2}{\pi}x$ for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$,
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}(u+k\pi)^{\alpha}\sin(u)du\geqslant\int_0^{\pi/2}(u+k\pi)^{\alpha}\sin(u)du\geqslant\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}(u+k\pi)^{\alpha}udu\geqslant\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}u^{\alpha+1}du\geqslant\frac{ (\pi/2)^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+2} $$
Thus the integral $$\int_1^{\infty}x^{\alpha}\sin(x)dx$$
diverges for $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Nice user name !